# Efficient MQTT broker to Kafka broker bridging

Tags: apache-kafka, mqtt

I need to stream incoming sensor data from Mqtt broker to Kafka broker. What are the most efficient tools  to do this ?

There are lots of brokers and some of them provide almost the same features.

Is there any broker that provides Kafka bridge plugin in an efficient way ?

Answer (score 2):

There is an MQTT Kafka Connect connector for that.

https://github.com/evokly/kafka-connect-mqtt
http://docs.datamountaineer.com/en/latest/mqtt.html

I have never used it but maybe it's worth to give it a try. let me know ;)

Comment: thanks. isn't it for just Confluent, is it? can i use it with pure apache kafka ?

Comment: It's for Kafka Connect so it works for pure Apache Kafka

Comment: Many different options for connecting MQTT and Kafka are treated here: https://medium.com/python-point/mqtt-and-kafka-8e470eff606b

Answer (score 2):

As alternative to Kafka Connect and a MQTT connector, you could also use the Confluent MQTT Proxy for this. If your only reason to have a MQTT Broker, then this is the much easier and more lightweight setup because you do not need a MQTT Broker this way. MQTT Proxy works the same way like Kafka' REST Proxy.

See this [example of how to combine MQTT with Apache Kafka](http://www.kai-waehner.de/blog/2018/08/02/deep-learning-kafka-ksql-udf-anomaly-detection-mqtt-iot-sensor/). Or go directly to the Github code: "[Deep Learning UDF for KSQL for Streaming Anomaly Detection of MQTT IoT Sensor Data](https://github.com/kaiwaehner/ksql-udf-deep-learning-mqtt-iot)".